# Ideas Needed : Ways to display list of list of data in iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa, list, tableview

I'm currently developing an iPad app.

On a specific view, I have to display some informations as this form :

- Item1 : DATA
- - Item1-1 : DATA
- - Item1-2 : DATA
- - Item1-3 : DATA
- - - Item1-3-1 : DATA
- Item2 : DATA
- - Item2-1 : DATA
- - Item2-2 : DATA
- Item3 : DATA
- Item4 : DATA
- ...

information1 : DATA can be more than one line long.
information2 : Sometimes an item will have an action
information3 : I think it would be better that everything is displayed in the same view, not in a different level (ie, != than clicking on a title segues you to another view with a list)

There is no real limit in sublists depth, although I shouldn't have more than a couples of nested list. I wanted to render it in a more fancy way than displaying a webview with a lot of < ul > < li > ...

I've though of `UITableView` inside `UITableViewCell`, but i'm afraid it might get messy in the end.

Any ideas ?
Thanks !

EDIT : I don't know if its really clear that what I'd like is more a way to represent a html-< table >-like than real nested list. The way i've represented it is not items with subitems etc but subitems should only be indented. All the data must be visible from the same view..

Answer (score 1):

The canonical way to display that kind of information is through a `UINavigationController` chaining `UITableViewController`s. You may find many examples of that design around, not the least in many Apple app (Mail, System Settings, and others).

If you are looking into a more original presentation, you could take inspiration from the [Clear app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/clear/id493136154?mt=8), which does a lot do handles nested tables in a novel way. Clear also does a lot of custom gesture handling: it is not necessary that you also implement that, but the interesting point is the way they hide and show nested table rows "in-place" instead of changing view altogether.

There is also a [github project](https://github.com/mystcolor/JTGestureBasedTableViewDemo) showcasing that technique.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do already use a Navigation controller and some TableViews. But here its a different problem. My app is going to replace a website, which has a part where there is a table, more or less like a spreadsheet. The list that i've shown represent more indentation than real nested list.. Is it more clear ?